# Could John Oliver be (inadvertently?) launching DOS attacks?

Tags: denial-of-service

Occasionally on his show, John Oliver points his viewers to the comments section of websites for companies/organizations that have done something putatively nefarious. For instance, when he pointed his viewers to the FCC's website to comment about net neutrality, [the FCC was subject to a DOS attack](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/06/12/fcc-dosed-into-silence-as-john-oliver-roused-net-neutrality-trolls/).

Now, in that case, it seems the FCC was subject to an intentional, coordinated, and (at least partially) automated DOS attack. If, on the other hand, the roughly 1 million people who watch the show all followed John Oliver's lead and relatively quickly after his announcement commented on the site (just once, so that it is "legitimate" commenting, not spamming) would that be a sufficient amount of traffic to generate a DOS attack on a typical modern website (I apologize for the infuriatingly vague "typical modern website")?

Comment: I have no idea who John Oliver is, but what @Mark said in his answer.  This has been seen before due to Slashdot, HackerNews, Reddit, the Wall Street Journal, and any other MSM channel that can expose a site to enough eyeballs to spike traffic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in the day, this was called the [Slashdot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect).  Accidentally DoSing a site through sudden popularity is nothing new.